# receive rosbag play topics

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i want to receive rosbag play topics and use them in may source is there any help?

i use

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/worldmodel/objects", 1000, chatterCallback);
```

but when i run rosbag play *.bag --clock i received this error :

```
ERROR] [1364626445.198828503]: Client [/listener] wants topic /worldmodel/objects to have datatype/md5sum [std_msgs/String/992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1], but our version has [worldmodel_msgs/ObjectModel/f9cae8b2109e6f4fe92735ca9596083c]. Dropping connection.
```

what shuold i do now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59595/receive-rosbag-play-topics/) by [MMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/1271/mmb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message is telling you that your subscriber is expecting a std_msgs/String, but the message is actually a worldmodel_msgs/ObjectModel. You should modify your subscriber to subscribe to the correct message type which is worldmodel_msgs/ObjectModel

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1